# Polymer 1.0 dom-repeat display index starting at 1

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer 1.0 to create a shopping/checkout cart. I have customers who may want to ship their order to multiple addresses. In the receipt, I need to list all the addresses with an index:

Address 1
John Doe
1234 Main St
...

Address 2
Jane Smith
999 Broadway
...

How do I get the index to start at 1 instead of 0?

```
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{shipping_details}}" as="address">
        <div>Address <span>{{index}}</span></div>
        <div>{{address.name}}</div>
        <div>{{address.line1}}</div>
    </template>
```

This is a simplification of my actual  code, but the principle is the same. I have tried to make a js function that takes the index as a parameter and sets the innerHTML to index++, but I don't know what event it should fire on or how to get it to call the function.

```
    <div>Address <span on-some-event="displayIndex(index)"></span></div>
```

I am new to all of this, so you can't go in to too much detail about how to make this work. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) for this.

**Instead of this**:

`<span on-some-event="displayIndex(index)"></span>`

**Do this**:

`<span>{{displayIndex(index)}}</span>`

**When `displayIndex` is this**:

```
function (index) {
    return index + 1;
}
```

Note:
`displayIndex` can be

1. a method on the element prototype

```html
<dom-module id="cart-addresses">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{shipping_details}}" as="address">
        <div>Address <span>{{displayIndex(index)}}</span></div>
        <div>{{address.name}}</div>
        <div>{{address.line1}}</div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'cart-addresses',
            ...
            displayIndex: function(index) {
                return index + 1;
            }
            ...
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

2. a method attached to an auto-binding template

```html
    <template is="dom-bind">
        ...             
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{shipping_details}}" as="address">
            <div>Address <span>{{displayIndex(index)}}</span></div>
            <div>{{address.name}}</div>
            <div>{{address.line1}}</div>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        var template = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-bind"]');

        ...

        template.displayIndex = function (index) {
            return index + 1;
        };
    </script>
```